# How to use a regular expression to find delimited needles within a haystack in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript, how can I use a regular expression to iterate through a string to isolate all occurances of strings starting with a '{' and ending with a '}' character?

So, for example the haystack string may be:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor {sit} amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. {Praesent} tincidunt, sapien non ultricies posuere, justo felis {placerat erat}, a laoreet felis justo in nisl. Donec.
```

The function would therefore need to return the following values:

1. sit
2. Praesent
3. placerat erat

All help appreciated!

Comment: Can you be sure that braces are never nested `{like {this} for example}`?

Comment: Yes, thanks for checking though. In this instance, the needles will never be nested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string.match(/{.*?}/g);
```

To elaborate: we use the match method for Strings to execute a regexp search. The `g` at the end of the regexp stand for 'global' and means find all matches. When executed in `g` mode the match method returns an array of all matches.

As for the regexp itself, its rather simple. Just find zero or more (`*`) instances of any character (`.`) between `{` and `}`.

Comment: Many thanks for the incredibly quick reply, works like a charm!

Comment: Since `{` and `}` are special characters in regular expressions, they should always be escaped (`\{` and `\}`). In this case, the context makes their intended meaning clear, but this may not always be the case. Plus, some regex engine may treat this as a Syntax Error.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
var subject = 'Lorem ipsum dolor {sit} amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. {Praesent} tincidunt, sapien non ultricies posuere, justo felis {placerat erat}, a laoreet felis justo in nisl. Donec.'
subject.match(/\{[^}]+\}/g);
```

Note that it still contains the `{` and `}`.